# Attaching functions to movable locators

Tags: functions, locator

I'm trying to create a manipulate plot showing the electric field due to a collection of point charges. At the moment I've created such a plot which allows the x and y positions of each charge to be manipulated using sliders, however what I would particularly like to do is to be able to click and drag the points on the plot. I have created locators which can be manipulated like so, however I can't work out how to attach a function to them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code of this [Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DroppingATestChargeIntoAnElectricField/) might be helpful.

Comment: It should be straightforward, if you use the LocatorPane or Manipulate with the Locator as the Control. You just fix the points p1, p2,... as the locator coordinates and the same values give for the points of your present plot. I cannot help more without the code of your present attempt. This is also a general rule here: that is to show what you have already done in the direction.

Answer (score 2):

an example I wrote some months ago for inspiration

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@esp[q3D[p], p3D[p], {x, y, z}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  (*ContourPlot Options*)
  Contours -> 20,
  ContourLabels -> All, (*Tooltip Labels*)
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  PlotRange -> 11,
  ImageSize -> 850 ],

 (*--Controls--*)(*use Alt-Click to set and delete Locators *)
 (*LocatorAutoCreate->{1,10} allows min 1 max 10 Locators*)
 {{p, {{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}}, {-9, -9}, {9, 9}, Locator, 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> {1, 10}}, {z, 0, 5 (*Slider for zPlane *)},

 (*--Manipulate Options--*)
 Deployed -> True,
 Initialization :> ((*esp=ElectroStaticPotential*)
   esp[q_, p_, r_] := Sum[q[[i]]/Norm[r - p[[i]]], {i, Length[p]}];
   k = 9; (*constant*)
   p3D[p_] := Table[p[[i]]~Join~{0}, {i, Length@p}];
   q3D[p_] := Table[k (-1)^i, {i, Length@p}];)
 (*Manipulate**)]
```

Can you explain what functionality you want?